# How to assign a past date while uploading a photo via Facebook Graph API, so that it gets placed at the right point in Timeline?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, timestamp, facebook-timeline

Using the Facebook Graph API, I have been able to upload a photo. It is an old scanned photo. I would now like to modify the timestamp, so that it is shown at the appropriate point in the timeline. Does the API provide a way to do this?

Here is an article that says we can assign past dates to Facebook Timeline Posts - http://www.allfacebook.com/facebook-timeline-timestamp-2011-10 . I want to assign a past date to a photo I uploaded, and I would like to do it via the Graph API. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: look at this: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/posting-past-actions/